# crm 2011 bulk delete email notifications - how is URL constructed?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

CRM 2011 RU18 On Premise. Our bulk delete emails notifications get sent fine. But the URL in the emails is not correct. The URL follows the line that reads:

To view the status of the job, either: Click (URL) or ....

The jobs work fine and we get the emails post job complete BUT the URL is wrong.

Does anyone know HOW CRM constructs the URL? i.e. where is it looking for the start of the URL i.e. the bit that is http(or https)://servername as this is the incorrect bit for us...

I've checked the registry and a lot of the config db with no luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Email Templates and you should see a few System Job templates for Bulk Delete jobs. The one you want should be called "Bulk Deletion Task Completion Template." You can edit the template to include the correct server URL here.